# In Eclipse, my device not detected

Tags: android, eclipse

My android smartphone device is no longer being detected in Eclipse.  I have tried to restart Eclipse, my system and my device also which does not fix it.

My device is a 'Micromax canvas2' smartphone.  My drivers are installed.  I checked with other Samsung devices with a samsung driver and it works correctly.

I checked all the settings.  Also check with eclipse Windows > Show view > Other .. > Device but no device found.

Why isn't my device found and how do I fix it?

Comment: do you have usb debugging enabled on the device?

Comment: USB Debugging enabled? If your device is on 4.2.2 is your PC on the whitelist?

Comment: Bill thanks but I tried thoes answer

Comment: thanks! to all for answering .I solved this problem. Stack overflow ROCKS!  i just download latest driver form my mobile provider's site and this solved my problem!!I hope old driver is corrupted !!

Comment: I have same problem is here, can you give me link that you downloaded the micromax usb driver.

Comment: @nileshwani sorry micromax have changed UI and removed link.. let me know if you need driver. I have this exe.

Comment: yes i need that .exe.

Comment: @nilesh your Email???

Comment: @Bhavin i download the driver from the micromax site of canvas2 A110 and its worked fine. thanks

Comment: @nilesh wani welcome bro :) I have downloaded the same device driver :)

Comment: @Bhavin what is url when connecting android power device to the eclipse(means localhost wamp server). I wrote url like a 1)http://10.0.2.2:80/abc/mobile/index.ws.php 2) http://192.168.115.116/bookingscape/mobile/index.ws.php ,but not working.

Comment: @nileshwani for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240338/http-10-0-2-2-works-on-the-android-emulator-but-not-on-android-device-used-as

Answer (score 3):

Try Killing the adb server and restarting it thru command prompt

go to your android skd directory where ever you have kept it
and traverse to adb.exe which you will find inside platform-tools..

May be this will help you. same happened with me many times. I just restart the server at that time

[image]

Comment: I have kill exe with task manger

Comment: thanks Abhinav!! is there any other suggestion??

Comment: just want you to try it using command prompt. Other wise I have no other way  to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit ~/.android/adb_usb.ini (or if you are running as root, check /root/.android)
Add 0x1bbb to the end of the file if it already exists, otherwise do: echo 0x1bbb >> adb_usb.ini
adb kill-server
adb start-server
Check output of adb devices for your device
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav,I tried this but device can't detect!!

Comment: May I know ?Device Name ?

Comment: I think Micromax  does not support . Not sure

Comment: Hi, Check with this solution.(http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41076/micromax-a57-is-not-displayed-in-eclipse-device-list/44130#44130). Its working fine for me with Micromax Devices. Hope, this would be helpful. Thanks.