# Why won't eclipse detect my android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, device-driver, mobile-phones

I am using the **Alcatel One Touch 918N** as my device in running my code from eclipse. The device seems to appear on my computer since it is able to read the files stored in it but the problem is it does not appear on the **Devices** tab in eclipse.

I've tried following the instructions from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers), and downloaded the USB Driver from this [site](http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/support/faq/usbdriver.html) but when i tried installing the driver, it still says that:

**Windows was unable to install your Alcatel Android phone** and **Windows could not find driver software for your device**.

Did I do something wrong? Did I perhaps downloaded the wrong USB Driver? Pls help!

Comment: Are you trying to build android application?

Comment: yep! but im unable to do so since it does not detect the device on eclipse in the first place.

Comment: see if your device is shown by running the command "adb devices" ? if not try a "adb kill-server" followed by "adb start-server" and try again, if not listed yet, then the problem is with driver

Comment: @stan07 have you installed the drivers. check the link http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: I've tried it and it's still not on the list. So I assume the problem is with the driver? What should I do with it?

Comment: you can try installing the driver from your phone manufacturer site if that helps.

Comment: @Raghunandan I've downloaded the USB Driver from [here](http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/support/faq/usbdriver.html) and it's a .rar file. How do you exactly install it?

Comment: extract the rar file. see if there is install.exe file. double click and install the driver. you see the faq in the site for further help

Comment: I extracted the rar file but there is no install.exe found inside the folders. Is there any other way to install the USB Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I just followed the steps here:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41076/micromax-a57-is-not-displayed-in-eclipse-device-list/44130#44130

Hope this helps to those whose devices cannot be detected by eclipse

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to build android application using eclipse and trying to run the application in the device, then

1. go to **settings**
2. then go to **applications**
3. then go to **development**
4. then check **debugging**

Then you can install your application using eclipse.

Comment: Then do: 1. Run as run configurations  2. Go to target tab   3. For now, click Always prompt to pick device ,then click apply and click run.  Then it will show Android Device Chooser. Now choose your android device.

Comment: According to your post, you need to install the driver manually. Download it from http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/support/faq/usbdriver.html

Comment: May be this(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PohlsESPkes) will help to install the driver manually

Comment: thats exactly what I did and it still didn't work. Instead it displayed this: "Windows was unable to install your Alcatel Android phone and Windows could not find driver software for your device"

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. Actually, I do use ubuntu. May be you should look at the phone official site.

Comment: One guy had the same problem and he solved by installing latest driver. He said that "i just download latest driver form my mobile provider's site and this solved my problem!!I hope old driver is corrupted". And I found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547183/eclipse-my-device-not-detected?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Micromax A52, on linux, and tried, Android's official guide for Hardware devices at : [Using Hardware Device](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). However, you'll need to find out your Alcatel's USB vendor id.

Comment: yeah but im using it on Windows 7. I think the USB vendor id part only applies on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my huawei y320, and it was simple:

1. put the device as data storage (I speak spanish, so i think that's the way it is written)
2. follow all the normal steps, go to developer option and enable usb debugging and wait