# micromax a111 is not detected by adb

Tags: android, usb, device, device-driver, adb

Recently i've purchased micromax a111 android device. I am android developer. So tried this device for debugging option. But the adb is not able to detect the device. I have change the settings also, but not working out. If any one have the solution please help me regarding this.

Comment: Have you enable the usb dubugging in settings-developers options ??

Comment: change usb mode to media storage, enable unknown resources, enable usb debugging.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see I have faced this issue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547183/in-eclipse-my-device-not-detected just re install your driver

Comment: yes i have enable the debugging option and unknown resource also. But still the Adb not able to detect this device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

micromax doesn't have official PC-Suite, so you need to download a third party PC-Suite like Moborobo or Mobogenie, after installation you can restart the system, now your mobile will be detected.

Comment: Thank you Mohan. The Mobogenie pc suite is working fine. Thank for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the vendor id to adb_usb.ini
http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux-android:adb-trace

Answer (score 1):

Find the device vendor id, it would be like 0x1A9A.
Add that vendor id to adb_usb.in located at C:\Users[Login-User].android\

the .android folder might not be visible as it is an hidden folder.

Restart the adb by following command
adb kill-server
adb devices

and you will be able to see your device.

Answer (score 1):

Start USB debugging(in settings>applications>developer options) on device first.

And still there is problem, try following link. http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

It helped me to detect my Micromax Canvas Hd.

I tied Motorola's "22b8" value and it worked for Micromax. Also on friends PC the idea worked. We done it for Ubuntu 32 and 64 bi

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem While Using Micromax Unite2 Device with Android Studio

So I installed PdaNetA4190.exe Software (3.09 MB)

downloaded from the site 
 http://pdanet.co/a/
(Available for Windows as well as Mac)

PdaNetA4190.exe would work all the devices (include Samsung) and even ask that
for which device you want to use while downloading process

Tutorial link to Install the PdaNet

http://pdanet-for-android.software.informer.com/

Answer (score -1):

Replace the file under ~/.android/adb_usb.ini with the following contents:

0x18d1
0x0bb4
0x04e8
0x22b8
0x1004
0x12D1
0x0502
0x0FCE
0x0489
0x413c
0x0955
0x091E
0x04dd
0x19D2
0x0482
0x10A9
0x05c6
0x2257
0x0409
0x04DA
0x0930
0x1F53
0x2116
0x0b05
0x0471
0x0451
0x0408
0x1d91
0x040a
0x143c
0x1ebf
0x23e6
0x1e0e
0x0525
0x1219
0x17EF
0x2006
0x22d9
0x1C9E
0x0B57
0x24e3
0x1bbb
0x0F1C
0x0414
0x2420
0xE040
0x1D4D
0x0E79
0x1662
0x05C6
0x19D2
0x9015
0x0489
0x04CC
0x0000
0x19d2
0x12d1
0x04cc
0x17ef
0x0fce
0x2207
0x2717