# Unable to start ADB server while connecting to Micromax A111 phone to PC

Tags: android, adb

I am unable to connect the micromax A111 phone to PC while ADB server is running and it is connecting if i kill the server.. when i am trying to start the server after connecting the mobile to PC, then the following error occurs::

D:\Android Studio SDK\platform-tools>adb start-server
adb server is out of date.  killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *

This Problem is getting only when i use android studio..

I had tried MoboRobo, MoboGenie.. but no use..

Comment: Have you changed SDK location ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346802/micromax-a111-is-not-detected-by-adb

Comment: How to change the sdk location.. and to where i should change @ shanmugasundharam-selvadurai

Comment: Hi Momin Al Aziz... the solution is working only when i use eclipse but not for Android Studio